# google_places API returned unexpected types

Tags: r, google-places-api

I am using places API from google map in R. In the following example, I noticed that some unexpected place_types are returned.

In the example, I only expected to get places with the type `establishment`, but the first and the last records are not `establishment`. Why does this happen? Does this only happen for `establishment`? I checked Table 2 in the [page](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/supported_types), but it does not tell anything.

```
> google_places(location = c(50.116921, 8.665373),
+               place_type = "establishment",
+               radius = 10,
+               key = api_key)$results%>%select(c("name", "types"))
The radar argument is now deprecated
                                 name                                              types
1                           Frankfurt                                locality, political
2                    World Bank Group    bank, finance, point_of_interest, establishment
3         Dulce Chocolate & Ice Cream      food, point_of_interest, store, establishment
4         Salädchen Frankfurt Westend restaurant, food, point_of_interest, establishment
5         MFS International (UK) Ltd.          finance, point_of_interest, establishment
6                            Occidens                   point_of_interest, establishment
7       OBM Baumaschinen-Handels-GmbH                   point_of_interest, establishment
8   International Finance Corporation          finance, point_of_interest, establishment
9  BANCO ITAU BBA INTERNATIONAL, S.A.    bank, finance, point_of_interest, establishment
10                      Innenstadt II        sublocality_level_1, sublocality, political
```

The session info follows:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.6.1 (2019-07-05)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=German_Germany.1252  LC_CTYPE=German_Germany.1252    LC_MONETARY=German_Germany.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                    LC_TIME=German_Germany.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices datasets  parallel  utils     methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] googleway_2.7.1   tfdatasets_2.2.0  keras_2.3.0.0     tensorflow_2.2.0  wesanderson_0.3.6 RPostgres_1.2.0   doParallel_1.0.15 iterators_1.0.12  foreach_1.5.0     logging_0.10-108  fastDummies_1.6.1
[12] MCI_1.3.3         data.table_1.13.0 DBI_1.1.0         forcats_0.5.0     stringr_1.4.0     dplyr_1.0.1       purrr_0.3.4       readr_1.3.1       tidyr_1.1.1       tibble_3.0.3      ggplot2_3.3.2    
[23] tidyverse_1.3.0  

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] httr_1.4.2         bit64_4.0.2        jsonlite_1.7.0     modelr_0.1.8       shiny_1.5.0        assertthat_0.2.1   blob_1.2.1         cellranger_1.1.0   yaml_2.2.0         pillar_1.4.6      
[11] backports_1.1.4    lattice_0.20-38    glue_1.4.1         reticulate_1.16    digest_0.6.25      promises_1.1.1     rvest_0.3.6        colorspace_1.4-1   httpuv_1.5.4       htmltools_0.5.0   
[21] Matrix_1.2-18      pkgconfig_2.0.3    broom_0.7.0        haven_2.3.1        xtable_1.8-4       scales_1.0.0       whisker_0.4        later_1.1.0.1      tfestimators_1.9.1 generics_0.0.2    
[31] ellipsis_0.3.1     withr_2.2.0        cli_2.0.2          mime_0.9           magrittr_1.5       crayon_1.3.4       readxl_1.3.1       fs_1.5.0           fansi_0.4.1        xml2_1.3.2        
[41] tools_3.6.1        hms_0.5.3          lifecycle_0.2.0    munsell_0.5.0      reprex_0.3.0       compiler_3.6.1     forge_0.2.0        rlang_0.4.7        grid_3.6.1         rstudioapi_0.11   
[51] htmlwidgets_1.5.1  base64enc_0.1-3    gtable_0.3.0       codetools_0.2-16   curl_4.3           R6_2.4.1           tfruns_1.4         lubridate_1.7.4    fastmap_1.0.1      bit_4.0.4         
[61] zeallot_0.1.0      stringi_1.4.3      Rcpp_1.0.1         vctrs_0.3.2        dbplyr_1.4.4       tidyselect_1.1.0
```

Comment: It says "Note: The types below are not supported in the type filter of a place search."  in the header to [table2](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/supported_types#table2) - I guess that might be it?

Comment: @alex_jwb90 yes, you are right. However, rather than giving a warning or error message, the code in the example still works. Isn't it kind of confusing?

Comment: it's a google service, so I would be surprised if it wasn't confusing. but perhaps there *is* a warning and it's just not passed through by the R package? you might try sending the request "raw" to the API and see what you get back: `raw_search_result <- httr::content(httr::GET(paste0('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=50.116921,8.665373&radius=10&type=establishment&key=',api_key)))`